# AWS CloudFront Leverage browser caching not working

Tags: browser-cache, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to set following Origin Custom Headers

```
Header Name: Cache-Control
Value: max-age=31536000
```

[image: AWS CloudFront error]

But it is giving `com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidArgumentException: The parameter HeaderName : Cache-Control is not allowed. (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument;` error.

I tried multiple ways along with setting the Minimum TTL, Default TTL, and Maximum TTL, but no help.

Comment: Custom Origin Headers are sent *from* CloudFront *to* the Origin server, which is not what you are trying to do... it appears you are trying to add response headers at CloudFront because your origin isn't returning them.  Is that correct?

Comment: If so, [I have answered this question at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/770469/153161).  There is not a built-in setting to add these response headers in CloudFront.  If you can add them at the origin, add them at the origin... otherwise you can add them at CloudFront using a Lambda@Edge Origin Response trigger to add the headers.  Example provided at SF.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to get good ratings on gtmetrix page score by leveraging browser caching! If you are serving content from S3 through cloudfront, then you need to add the following headers to objects in S3 while uploading files to S3.
Expires: {some future date}

Bonus: You do not need to specify this header for every object individually. You can upload a bunch of files together on S3, click next, and then on the screen that asks S3 storage class, scroll down and add these headers. And don't forget to click save!

[image]